# SQLite LIMIT OFFSET and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table Test1 => `ID(INT), NAME(VARCHAR)` having
values like `(1,'One'), (2,'two') ..... (51,'Fifty-one')`

I want sum of `ID` of last 5 rows whose `ID` is divisible by 5. I tried following query but not getting any output:

```
SELECT SUM(ID) FROM Test1 WHERE id%5 = 0 LIMIT 5 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test1)
```

So answer should be 50+45+40+35+30=200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use LIMIT without ORDER BY. Only with ORDER BY is the order in your result set guaranteed and only then LIMIT makes sense.

Moreover you use SUM without a GROUP BY. That gives you one result row. Then you use LIMIT on your results, which is still one result row.

And what is the offset supposed to do? You want to start after the last record in the table? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Here is the query with ORDER BY and SUM after LIMIT:

```
select sum(id)
from 
(
  select id
  from test1 
  where id % 5 = 0
  order by id desc
  limit 5
) last5;
```